# Deleting contents of all entries in field in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, null

In QGIS, how can you delete all of the entries in a field in an attribute table? If you go to a particular entry in a field, you can delete that entry, but how can you delete all of the entries in the field?

I see lots of posts for how to delete the field, but not how to keep the field but delete all of the entries in the field.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the field calculator to update the field to `''`, aka an empty field. Beware that this is not `NULL`.

As J.R pointed out in the comments, `null` provides a `NULL`-value in your field.

Comment: I think '' will return an empty string for text field but null for numeric field. If you want to get null value rather than an empty string you may use "null" (without any quote) as expression in the field calculator

Answer (score 6):

After selecting the layer, use this script in the Python Editor of QGIS:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# make a dictionary for indexed NULL value
null_attr = {i: NULL for i in range(layer.fields().count())}
# null_attr: {0: NULL, 1: NULL, 2: NULL, ...}

layer.startEditing()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    layer.changeAttributeValues(feature.id(), null_attr)
    
layer.commitChanges()
```

[image]